# How to run a function after you find something in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a randomized set of input elements that appear when users select different options on a form.  I want to find all the input boxes within a certain div by their classname and then call a function that sets those items to an array of objects.  So far I have this:

```
$('.div-class-name').find('input.input-class-name:textbox')
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  I know what needs to go into the function once it is called but I don't know how to call it. How do I call a function after a find for all the returned elements?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "sets those items to an array of objects?"  Have you looked at jQuery's `each` method?

Comment: Look into jQuery's [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method. You can then use your function by calling it on `$(this)` inside the callback to `each`. Looks something like this: `$(selector).find(selector).each(function() {your_function($this);});`.

Comment: The `.find()` selector returns itself an array of elements. What about assigning its return to a variable and then iterate over it? As mentioned in previous comments, `.each()` also does it.

Answer (score 13):

```
$('.div-class-name').find('input.input-class-name').each(function(el) {
    //this will run for each matching input
    console.log($(this)); //$(this) is a jquery reference to the element in the list of matching ones
});
```

Comment: What if I don't want to loop using 'each'. I just want to run the function on the first one only.

Comment: You can just find the first element and do whatever you want with it: 
const firstMatch = $('.div-class-name').first('input.input-class-name');

Answer (score 0):

Please do it like this:

```
function load(i){
    $('.div-class-name').find('input.input-class-name:textbox');
}
function makeDrag(){
  //does something here
}
$.when(load(i)).then(makeDrag());
```

Comment: Why would you use .when() for this when load isn't returning a Deferred? It is just going to be resolved immediately.